# why my non-clustered index wasn't used

Tags: sql-server

I'm new to sql server. I'm using sql server express 2014. I have NEVER had to deal with indexes.

I've made the following table structure to experiment with indexes

[image]

Given the table is supposed to store the score a student scored for each assignment, a lecturer may want to filter the data on assignment ID just to see who scored the highest on a particular assignment for example.

The following screenshot shows the query and the nonclustered index I created. However the execution plan says it wasn't used why?

[image]

Here is the definition
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The index does match the query but the table is extremely small. Scanning it accesses its only page. Using the index accesses two pages.

Make the index covering or add way more data. Both are actually good ways to try out indexes and understand them. You should try both.

Comment: LOL Thanks it shows how naive Iam when it comes to sql LOOOOL.

Comment: This is not a trivial piece of knowledge at all. The question was totally valid.

Comment: https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/using-covering-indexes-to-improve-query-performance/ Added this because I thought it was a good explaination. May help my fellow coders one day

Answer (score 0):

When you have small amount of data, like 5 rows in here, indexes aren't really being used because the whole data is most likely just 1 page. Because you're selecting "*" the whole page must be accessed anyhow because the non-clustered index only contains the keys in it, so fetching that one page using the index would probably be twice as expensive.

You can test how many pages would be used with and without the index by first running "set statistics io on". When you run the statement you'll see number of pages in the messages tab. To compare it when the index is used you can run "select * from Submissions with (index (index_name_here)) where AssignmentID = 2"